# Why make a extern variable a reference?

Tags: c++, reference, extern

I stumbled upon some code like this:

```
extern Space::MyClass &Global;
```

I know [about extern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/461834), but my question is, why would someone put the ampersand there? What's the difference between that and the following?

```
extern Space::MyClass Global;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extern` must match the actual definition of the variable.

Presumably one of the other units contains:

```
 Space::MyClass &Global = whatever....;
```

That means that you have to pick it up with `extern Space::MyClass &Global;`. Mismatching the types in an `extern` declaration causes undefined behaviour (no diagnostic required).

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the one you found has to be declared to refer to something else. Possibly it is part of a conditional-compilation configuration trick.